# How can I make a cron job to start a VPN at a specified time?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, vpn, systemd

I recently switched to Ubuntu from windows and I'm using an nordvpn. Everything works great, the CLI is very easy to use. I want the VPN to turn on everyday at 7am and turn off at 7pm. This seems like a perfect time for a Cron job. So, I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

nordvpn c p2p
sleep $1
nordvpn d
```

My crontab file is as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 7 * * * /scripts/nordvpnBurst.sh 12h
```

I have tried other scripts in the same location as the above script, they work fine. When I run this script in a terminal window (either as root or not) it runs perfectly. However when running from crontab it never connects to the VPN.
I made a script with only the disconnect line, and that runs fine through Cron. So it's just the connect line that it struggles with.

I have also tried setting up a systemd service to accomplish the same thing, and again the disconnect command works fine but the connect command doesn't.

I've tried editing my personal user's crontab as well as doing it as the root (sudo).

I've tried directly editing the the crontab file located at `/etc/crontab` to no avail as well.

I've been trying to figure this out for several days now and I can't find a solution online that works for me. Any insight?

Comment: sending the script to sleep for 12h and then continue the disconnect part seems very wrong to me. why don't you make to separate scripts that run at specified times? Or pass in a flag that makes the script connect or disconnect. but sleep 12h?

Comment: Does having a sleep for that long take up any resources?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's a bad design. You are unnecessarily coupling things together, which makes maintenance and debugging more difficult. If you had 2 cron jobs everyone knew when what happens right away instead of following the loop of the sleep. In addition, if you system crashes or anything happens to that sleeping process. You vpn won't shut down as expected. Now, debugging becomes more complicated, etc.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out finally. I had been editing the root crontab (sudo crontab -e) so it was running my script as root. My root user is not logged in to the vpn service and as such couldn't connect. Infuriating that it took me this long to figure it out.